# ck editor issue

Tags: php, ckeditor

i want to change the size of the text lets suppose i have a paragraph just like i am posting

this question and i want to change the word "paragraph" to heading one but when i select

that word and then select the option "HEADING 1" it change whole paragraph to heading one

instead the only word paragraph.what should i do to change only word paragraph to heading 1.

i am new to CK Editor.

i don't know the info i gave is sufficient or not if its not then please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are changing the paragraph format("HEADING 1"), it applies to the whole paragraph. If you wanna change just a particular word, you should alter the settings from Styles-> Inline styles.

Hope it helps